# MongoDB Collection Access

Tags: grails

I'm using MongoDB exclusively with a Grails REST app and the domain shown below. This respond call fails:

```
@Secured(['permitAll'])
def index() {
    respond Person.list()
}
```

with the error

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IllegalAccessException occurred when processing request: [GET] /teesheet/person
Class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GroovyBeanMarshaller can not access a member of class java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection with modifiers "public". Stacktrace follows:
Message: Class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GroovyBeanMarshaller can not access a member of class java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection with modifiers "public"
```

Attempting to convert the collection to JSON also fails with the same error.

```
def personList = Person.list() as JSON
```

The [low level API](https://fbflex.wordpress.com/2013/05/19/get-json-from-grails-mongo-gorm/) works.

```
package com.tworks.teesheet

import grails.rest.Resource

class Person {
  String name
  String firstName
  String lastName
  String email

  User userPerson

  TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")
  Date dateCreated = new Date()
  Date dateModified = new Date()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [Mongo for Grails](http://grails.org/plugin/mongodb) plugin, you need `@Entity` for domain classes...

```
import grails.persistence.Entity

@Entity
class Person {
  static mapWith = "mongo"

  String name
  String firstName
  String lastName
  String email

}
```

I added `mapWith="mongo"` since I wasn't sure if you're using the hibernate plugin alongside the mongo plugin; if you're not, remove hibernate, otherwise, it may [interfere](http://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/mongodb/manual/guide/2.%20Getting%20Started.html#2.2%20Combining%20MongoDB%20and%20Hibernate).

Comment: I'm not using the hibernate plugin or any other datastore, just MongoDB with the mongo 3.0.2 plugin and Grails 2.4.4. I added the @Entity and associated import and the error is resolved but the `respond Person.list()` returns the mongo cursor instead of the collection: `{"cursor":{"class":"com.mongodb.DBCursor","collection":{"DB":{"authenticated":false,...`

Comment: Just iterate the cursor, put `Person` objects in a `List`, return the list, though that's typically required when using the lower-level driver. Whenever I change mappings, I physically delete local directories where binaries are stored, then refresh/rebuild dependencies; (crap laying around causes problems), try that :-)

Comment: @Entity is not needed in a Mongo domain class or any other. That annotation is added by Grails during compilation with an AST transformation - there's no need to manually do this.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith Neglecting that tag was nothing but problems for me, and it seems to have addressed the OP's problem as well, not saying you're wrong, just commenting on experience.

Comment: So where is that documented?

Comment: @BurtBeckwith Nearly all tests for gorm/mongo use `@Entity`, https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/tree/master/grails-datastore-gorm-mongodb/src/test/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/mongo... As I said, it solved my issue, though I'm using an abstract base class for common properties, not sure if that's forcing the issue,

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using the low level calls to iterate using the cursor but it seems like the `respond Person.list()` should work. This code is working:

```
def cursor = Person.collection.find()
def items = []
try {
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        items << com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize(cursor.next())
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close()
}
log.info("items: ${items}")
render items
```